# Spring Application doesn't start due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm trying to deploy an application on heroku and came past several issues. The application is working in my IDE(Intellij) but when I try to run it with "heroku local -f Procfile.windows" I get this error:

```
11:30:03 PM web.1 |  2016-05-24 23:30:03.491  WARN 10368 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
11:30:03 PM web.1 |  2016-05-24 23:30:03.505 ERROR 10368 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
11:30:03 PM web.1 |  org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at cinemagic.main.App.main(App.java:27) [CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |  Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:185) ~[CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
11:30:03 PM web.1 |     ... 8 common frames omitted
```

The procfile looks like this:
    web: java -jar target\CinemaMagic-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>CinemaMagic</groupId>
<artifactId>CinemaMagic</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>cinemagic.main.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("cinemagic")
@EnableJpaRepositories("cinemagic.repositories")
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "cinemagic.model"})
@EnableScheduling
public class App extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/").setCachePeriod(0);
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For starters work with the framework instead of against/around the framework. Your dependencies are a mess and you aren't using the correct plugin.

First remove all of your plugins and replace with the `spring-boot-maven` plugin. (See also [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html#getting-started-maven-installation) for this).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Next cleanup your dependencies and use the proper (the Spring Boot managed) versions.

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Finally your application class is (somewhat) flawed you don't need that many annotations and you are extending a Spring Boot config class . What you are attempting to do in your overridden method is already provided by default by Spring Boot. So there is no need to do that. Also just put your `App` class in the `cinematic` top level package and everything else will be detected for you.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class App 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }

}
```

Now rebuild your jar and launch it.

**Note:** The main issue was the fact that you weren't using the Spring Boot maven plugin but tried to do that yourself.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you! I will keep in mind to start with a good maven build from now on :).

Answer (score 0):

Goto C:\Users\username.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot

and delete spring-boot-autoconfiguration and build your maven again.

It will Work it will generate again.